# cfgrid ext js rowdblclick listener not firing

Tags: extjs, coldfusion, cfgrid

In ColdFusion 2016, for this CFGRID example a double click on a row does nothing.  Everything else seems to work, just having an issue adding the listener.

https://www.sitepoint.com/applications-coldfusion-8/

A colleague confirmed it does work in CF10 so I assume the ExtJS has changed. Anyone know how to do this in CF2016?

```
function initGrid(){ 
   var grid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject("aaaGrid");
    grid.on("rowdblclick", showAAAForm); 
}
```

Comment: A colleague confirmed it does work in cf10 so I assume the extjs has changed. Anyone know how to do this in CF2016? `function initGrid(){  
  var grid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject("aaaGrid");  
 grid.on("rowdblclick", showAAAForm);
  }`

Comment: You might ask at cfml.salck.com, but odds are everyone will tell you to ditch CFGRID and move to jQuery DataTables or something else.

Comment: While I agree about ditching cfgid, if you must make it work, find out what version CF2016 uses and try searching for the event and ExtJS, ie "rowdbclick ExtJS". If it was deprecated, someone else has probably run into the same issue and may have posted a solution for later versions.

Comment: I found the solution! Replace rowdblclick with itemdblclick

 grid.on("itemdblclick", showAAAForm);